# gdb gives me infinite "Program received signal SIGTSTP" when I try to resume

Tags: gdb, pthreads

I was running vlc in gdb and used ^Z to interrupt it (because ^C was not working) .  After inspecting some stack frames and variables I tried to use "cont" to resume the program, but it kept giving me

```
Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user). 
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd8d8e700 (LWP 19285)] 
0x00007ffff700247c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
    from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

Actually, only the first line was the same.  The LWP id cycled between 19285 and 19284, and the address and function alternated as well.

I tried "cont -a" but it says
`-a' is meaningless in all-stop mode.

What is the proper procedure to resume both threads?

Answer (score 7):

While calling "cont" enough times (once per thread) should resume the application, what works best for me for resuming from ^Z is

```
signal SIGCONT
```

Note that trying "cont" first and then "signal SIGCONT" may leave gdb in a strange state.

Comment: This works. but in debugging a multithreaded KDE program I found dozens more threads continued to stop e.g.
`Thread 49 "multiqueue2:src" received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).`
`[Switching to Thread 0x7fff767fc700 (LWP 65)]`
and I had to enter `signal SIGCONT` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens because the SIGTSTP signal is not handled. When you resume execution, the program sees the signal and stops again.

According to the [documentation of GDB](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_120.html)

> Alternatively, if signal is zero, continue execution without giving a signal. This is useful when your program stopped on account of a signal and would ordinary see the signal when resumed with the continue command; `signal 0` causes it to resume without a signal.

So to answer your question, try performing the `signal 0` command in GDB, and it should resume execution.

Furthermore, if you do not wish the program to stop at SIGTSTP or any signal, you can use the `handle` command to define the behaviour of GDB when it receives signal. See further instructions on how to do this [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_39.html).